# How do I enable spread operator with plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread in Babel 7?

Tags: babeljs

I'm trying to enable the spread operator in my project using Babel, but since Babel has remove stage presets I'm having no luck getting spread operators to work with: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread

I've installed `plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` and added it to my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

But I'm still getting the following error:

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'objectRestSpread' isn't currently enabled 
 (28:3):

  26 |   onClick,
  27 |   text,
> 28 |   ...allProps
     |   ^
  29 | }) => {
  30 |   let Element = isStatic ? 'span' : renderAs;
  31 |   const props = modifiers.clean(allProps);

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread (https://git.io/vb4Ss) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

It suggests I add `@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread`. I have, it's in my `package.json`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your project directory structure like, and how are you calling Babel? Is it possible that your `.babelrc` file is just being ignored? See http://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#6x-vs-7x-babelrc-loading

Comment: I solved it earlier, but that's the correct solution. Put as answer. It's not clear initially upon migration that this is an important step. Tripped up many people by the looks of it.

Comment: @BugHunterUK Could you elaborate with your changes by adding an answer here? even reading their docs does not help.

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: I'm using Quasar framework, so my instructions may be very slightly different, but is mostly the same.

For the others like me who were spending hours on this issue that shouldn't have been in the first place, here's how I solved it:

1. Go to your directory where you currently have your `.babelrc` file.
2. Create a file called `babel.config.js` and add the following contents:

```
module.exports = {
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

3. Now, do an `npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread --save-dev`
4. Reload your server, running project. It should work now.

In my case, I didn't touch my `.babelrc` but just left it as it is and added the new config file. But others have had luck just copy pasting all the content in `.babelrc` into `babel.config.js`

Just my $0.02, (mods you can probably delete this part):

Honestly, Babel has become a can of worms. I don't understand why they constantly need to keep screwing up perfectly working implementations. I wish we'd be in a future where won't need to touch this time sink as anything wrong with Babel causes atleast 2 hours on average to fix.

Comment: I had a perfectly working build, now it fails. Your solution doesn't work for me. Not sure how they can just screw people up like this.

Comment: @MooseontheLoose Yeah, sorry about that, this is the problem with Babel. I had to try a lot of different combinations on trial and error to get it working. Sorry it didn't work for you mate. The number of changes they've made is just mind-boggling. I can't believe we don't have a decent alternative to Babel yet. It's about time we got rid of it!

Comment: This issue had me two days of pulling my hair out and hitting my head on the wall. Thanks so much.

Comment: Yeah, this didn't work for me either. I first tried to add it to the ```.babelrc``` file, no-go, that caused ```yarn dev``` to fail on startup. Adding it to ```babel.config.js``` didn't blow up the server, but the spread operator still gives a syntax error in a vue component. My project is a relatively new vue-cli project, created April 2020.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a solution, but I can tell you that I was in your shoes a few days ago (May 2020) and it turns out Babel (yet again) had deprecated something else. It broke my code that was pretty functional since I wrote the answer above. ____ Babel.